# Change 2 strings on load with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I try to replace two parts of a string in a lot of pages on page load.

In this case, I would like to replace:

```
<iframe width="890" height="514" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/
```

with a string and

```
?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

with another one. Tried to use

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.onload = clear; function clear() { document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/xxx/g, 'yyy'); } </script>
```

but that did not work.

It needs to be done on page load. Anybody an idea? Thank you!

Edit:

What I try to do, is to split a Youtube embed in a div. The part before the unique Youtube id needs to be replaced and the part after the id needs to be replaced. The complete link is something like:

```
<iframe width="890" height="514" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

The part before the xxxxxxxx and the part after the xxxxxxxx need to be changed on load to a more complete code including div's and classes.

Thank you!

Comment: Please define "did not work".

Comment: Is the original iframe being injected into the page via Javascript?  Meaning, if you view page source in your browser, does the iframe show up?

Comment: @ Teemu, the string (say <iframe width="890" height="514" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/) is not replaced, even when I put that in replace (/xxx/g.....)

@levi, yes, I can see the iframe in the source.

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to solve this issue? Then you can replace the xxxx part before it is displayed.

Comment: Hello S.Pols, I would not know how to fix that. When I try to replace for example:

replace('<iframe width=\"890\" height=\"514\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/', 'this other string');

The page goes blank.....